# Stage Dimensions are shown incorrect when embeded in HTML File

Tags: html, actionscript-3

I need to have a swf file that fills the entire html page. But sadly I fail to make it work as intended. Even thought the SWF does indeed fill the entire page, it's dimensions are shown wrong. here is what I am talking about: http://tinypic.com/r/w7k75i/6

As you can see, the swf is at the end of the window, but the dimension is 1024x768 (the text at the bottom left corner) and the "stage resize" event was never triggered (0- the last number). This works perfectly when oppening the swf on my PC, but not when embeded in an html page.

This is how I embed my SWF:

```
<body><script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='/B1D671CF-E532-4481-99AA-19F420D90332/netdefender/hui/ndhui.js?0=0&amp;0=0&amp;0=0'></script>
<div id="content">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    swfobject.embedSWF("SiteVali.swf", "content", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0");
</script>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is your dimension checking code only triggered by Event.RESIZE? You may just need to manually check the stageWidth and stageHeight values once after loading completes, as it won't fire the first time the swf is rendered, even if it's not the default size.

Comment: Yes...the stage dimensions are only checked on Event.RESIZE. I will try your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: This worked. Thanks :) I would choose it as the correct answer if you would have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting solution from comments:

Is your dimension checking code only triggered by Event.RESIZE? You may just need to manually check the stageWidth and stageHeight values once after loading completes, as it won't fire the first time the swf is rendered, even if it's not the default size.